# Bing Maps LoadMap() function zoom parameter

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I am trying to implement Bing Maps by passing a street address in the Find() function. The zoom parameter is not working in the LoadMap() function. Here is my code:

```
var map;

function GetMap() {
    var street = "Street address";
    var city = "City";
    var state = "State";
    var address = "";
    var zoom = 10;
    if (street != "") {
        address += street;
        zoom = 19;
    }
    if (city != "") {
        if (address != "")
            address += ", ";
        address += city;
    }
    if (state != "") {
        if (address != "")
            address += ", ";
        address += state;
    }

    map = new VEMap('bingMap');
    map.LoadMap(null, zoom, VEMapStyle.Hybrid, false, VEMapMode.Mode2D, true, 1);
    map.Find(null, address, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, FindCallback);
}

function FindCallback(layer, resultsArray) {
    var pin = new VEShape(VEShapeType.Pushpin, map.GetCenter());
    pin.SetCustomIcon("<img src='image url' width='30' />");
    map.AddShape(pin);
}
```

Any ideas why this won't zoom to 19?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 
 `map.LoadMap(null,`

try

`map.LoadMap(map.GetCenter()` or `map.LoadMap(new VELatLong(45,90)`

or use the

`map.SetCenterAndZoom((new VELatLong(lat, lng), zoom);`